# High CPU/Memory use by the vmcompute process

Tags: windows, docker, amazon-ecs

We are running a Windows 2019 cluster in AWS ECS.

From time to time the instances get problems with higher cpu and memory usage, not related to container usage

When checking the instances we can see that the vmcompute process have spiked its memory usage (commit) to up to 90% of the system memory, and having a average CPU usage of at least 30-40%

But I fail to understand why that is happening, and if it is a real issue?
Or if the memory and CPU usage will decrease when more load is put onto the containers?

Comment: Isn't vmcompute just showing the load on the virtual machine running in Hyper V? Have a look at the Hyper-V management console, there you'll see what the individual VMs are doing.

Comment: Vote to close: this needs to get moved to ServerFault